# Get the 0 value if No result in column -- MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following query

```
SELECT COUNT( iContactId ) AS Users, DATE( dCreatedAt ) AS ActivityDate 
FROM contacts WHERE iAppId =".$iAppId." 
AND DATE(dCreatedAt) IN (CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_DATE()-1 ) 
GROUP BY ActivityDate
```

by this i am getting

```
Users |ActivityDate
1     |2014-09-19
```

i want 0 if there is no match rows

e.g

```
Users |ActivityDate
0     |CURRENT_DATE()
0     | CURRENT_DATE()-1
```

How can i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use union

```
SELECT COUNT( iContactId ) AS Users, CURRENT_DATE() AS ActivityDate
FROM contacts WHERE iAppId =".$iAppId." 
AND DATE(dCreatedAt) = CURRENT_DATE()
UNION
SELECT COUNT( iContactId ) AS Users, CURRENT_DATE() - 1 AS ActivityDate 
FROM contacts WHERE iAppId =".$iAppId." 
AND DATE(dCreatedAt) = CURRENT_DATE() - 1
```

Comment: i am getting 20140920 as date format in matched rows date

Answer (score 1):

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT
COUNT(C.iContactId) AS Users,
DATE(C.dCreatedAt) AS ActivityDate 
FROM
contacts C
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT CURRENT_DATE() AS Dates FROM dual
        UNION
    SELECT CURRENT_DATE() - 1 AS Dates FROM dual
) D
    ON
        D.Dates = DATE(C.dCreatedAt)
WHERE
C.iAppId =".$iAppId."
GROUP BY
C.ActivityDate
```

Answer (score 0):

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT 
ISNULL( iContactId ,0) AS Users, 
DATE( dCreatedAt ) AS ActivityDate 
FROM contacts 
WHERE iAppId =".$iAppId." 
AND DATE(dCreatedAt) IN (CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_DATE()-1 ) 
GROUP BY ActivityDate
```

Comment: Sorry, Forgot to remove the count()

Comment: i need count and date both.

Comment: @pln cud you explain.

Answer (score 0):

In most answers this is used voor date substraction:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE() - 1
-> 20140919
```

This will result in impliciet type casting and date wil be casted to int, use this instead:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY
-> 2014-09-19
```

My solution

```
SELECT
    d.ActivityDate,
    COUNT(c.iContactId) Users
FROM
    (
    SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY ActivityDate FROM DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT CURRENT_DATE FROM DUAL
    ) d
LEFT JOIN
    contacts c
    ON DATE(c.dCreatedAt) = d.ActivityDate
    AND c.iAppId = " . $iAppId . "
GROUP BY d.ActivityDate
```